# Dollhouse lighting using SMD lights with CR2032 (how to bias an LED array)

Tags: batteries, lighting

I am a complete novice, so please be gentle.

I make 1:24 scale tiny dollhouses. So far I have powered them using 2x CR2032 batteries and 2 or 3 SMD (0402) warm white bulbs.

Usually the lights are just on for a few mins at a time and this is fine. I recently left one switched on for a week to see what would happen.

The bulbs dimmed, I replaced the batteries and all was well. A week later, however, the bulbs are dimmed right down (one barely there) and a change of battery did nothing.

I guess if I want to leave the lights switched on for any amount of time, I need to rethink things and use a resistor or even re-think the lighting altogether and move away from LED bulbs.

Ideally I would like to use a 1:24 scale dollhouse lighting kit, but with a 9V battery or similar (so that these items can be placed on bookcases) rather than a DC adapter.

I have found 1:12 scale dollhouse adaptors for 9 volt batteries, but not 1:24 (the size of the plug on the 1:24 scale lighting is smaller than 1:12.) These are [here (for reference.)](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/313543501713?hash=item4900a62791:g:5j8AAOSwyd9grmAN)

[1:24 scale lighting sets are available,](https://www.atriflesmall.co.uk/124th-scale-dolls-house-lights-and-fires/124th-scale-electrical-accessories/124th-scale-dolls-house-lighting-power-stripsockets-1641) but a bit overkill and I have no idea how I would change them to run off a 9V battery.

Can anyone help to suggest the best way forward? I am happy to do some trial and error.

Comment: I am confused, what is the actual question, why it stopped working with CR2032 or how to modify for 9V batteries? Well, it depends. Were the white LEDs in parallel or series? Were the CR2032 batteries in parallel or series? I.e. How were things wired?

Comment: I'm guessing the lack of a resistor has damaged one of the LEDs. Using LEDs without some sort of current limiting is just not an option. But don't abandon them, they're way more efficient than filament lamps.

Comment: White SMD LED typically runs at 3.3V, and will be fairly bright even at 5 to 10 mA. Running from 2x CR2032, you will need a (2*3-3.3)/0.008=330 ohms resistor in series with each LED. Running from 9V, you will need (9-3.3*2)/0.007=330 ohms resistor in series with every two LED in series. You can reduce the resistor to 220 ohms or even 150 ohms to make the LED brighter. Runtime should typically be at least 5 hours for CR2032 and 15 hours for 9V alkaline.

Comment: Odd that a change of (presumably new) battery did not correct the problem in the original circuit.   @Jubs666  Please help the community to understand which of the two circuits you are trying to maximize battery life?

Comment: @gatorback Not really, battery voltages vary and a small increase in voltage across an LED can produce a huge increase in current, especially as it starts to heat up and makes the current increase even more.

Comment: @Finbarr If you are indicating that a variance in battery voltage can produce a current that will burn out the LED, then yes this is entirely possible with a brittle (sensitive)  design.   I assumed that the OP  is using identical batteries from the same manufactured lot and is operating the LED in the (limited and small) linear range.

Comment: Thank you all for taking the time to reply - much appreciated.  The LEDs were in parallel and they were attached to one of these: https://www.amazon.co.uk/GTIWUNG-CR2032-Battery-Holder-Plastic-20Pcs-2x3V-Button-Switch/dp/B0823W1MX7/ref=sr_1_7_sspa?dchild=1&keywords=CR2032+switch&qid=1626191574&sr=8-7-spons&psc=1&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUExTjlZVEZBSlY3TVkwJmVuY3J5cHRlZElkPUEwMDQ2NTIzM00zSEg4T0ZVSFRJRyZlbmNyeXB0ZWRBZElkPUEwNTg1MjQzM0M5MzIzMDhaOEVZMiZ3aWRnZXROYW1lPXNwX210ZiZhY3Rpb249Y2xpY2tSZWRpcmVjdCZkb05vdExvZ0NsaWNrPXRydWU=

Comment: The batteries were both new and both Duracell. I replaced like for like and both at the same time. Battery life I am not so worried about. I am more worried about the light burning out - the dollhouses are sealed and therefore it makes it difficult to replace the lights. Batteries on the other hand are ok to be replaced as these sit outside.  This is what I make (for info):  https://www.etsy.com/shop/BookNooksUK.  Thanks again for all the advice :)

Answer (score 1):

The design goal is to correctly ***Bias the LED*** via calculating the current limiting resistor and add it to the circuit:

[image]

To calculate Rs, it is necessary to either ask the manufacturer for a data sheet **or** characterize (measure) Vf and If.  Carefully select your DC battery voltage (Vs).  Best practice is to ask the manufacture for the LED current / voltage curve.

The LED manufacturer or the device manufacturer should be able to provide you with the valid range of current which can drive a particular LED.  Try to the lower end of the range and this will maximize batter life.

Selecting a lower Vs (while maintaining a positive numerator) will reduce the value of Rs and less energy will be wasted in Rs at a particular current.  I hope its obvious that to calculate Rs: Vs must be greater than Vf.

If the OP's original LEDs were burnt out due to excessive current, then correctly biasing the replacement LEDs will enable a proper current that will prevent early burnout failure.

If the OP's question is actually how do I modify any of said 3 circuits for 9V or any other battery operation, then the answer lies in the calculation above.

May I suggest a PIR (Passive Infrared) motion detector to detect when someone is in front of the dollhouse and switch LED lighting on / off?  This would definitely increase the "wow!" factor.

Source: https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/diode/diode_8.html

Comment: Difficulty: \$V_f \approx V_{battery}\$ = calculation is pretty much impossible.  \$V_{battery}\$ also varies, making it a moving target.

Comment: " In practice, Vf is always greater VBattery."  So if I connect a 5V source (\$V_{battery}\$ to a 3V (\$V_f\$) LED through a current limiting resistor, then \$V_f\$ is greater than 5V - or did you mean something else?

Comment: @JRE,  thanks for the correction.  VBattery must be greater than VF, otherwise the diode would be in cutoff.  The numerator must be positive.

Comment: @gatorback - thank you so much for all the info. Once I get the lights sorted I will definitely have a look into a PIR - Great idea, especially as one of these sits in our local pub, if would be lovely if it lit up when people went to look at it :)

Comment: @Jubs666 Please consider posting a photo of the final product in your original posting: especially if you get the PIR working.